# javascript add time to answer by pressing a button or loose automatically

Tags: javascript, html, time

I'm doing a javascript code, and I want to do when you press the play button, starts counting 2 seconds. If you press the cat button or cube button, and is the correct answer, It would start counting 2 seconds to answer another time. If you don't click any button, you must loose automatically. But, when I press the play button, it starts counting the 2 seconds, and when I press the cat or cube button, the 2 seconds don't restart. Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const catbutton=document.getElementById('catbutton');
const cubebutton=document.getElementById('cubebutton');
const image=document.getElementById('image');
const puntuation=document.getElementById('puntuation');
const puntuator=document.getElementById('puntuator');
const pantplay=document.getElementById('pantplay');
const pantprincipal=document.getElementById('pantalla-principal');
const closepunt=document.getElementById('accionador');
const playbutton=document.getElementById('playbutton');
function closepuntuation(){
    puntuator.style="display: none";
    pantplay.style="display: none";
    pantprincipal.style="display: ";
    x=0;
}
var timeoutID;
playbutton.onclick=function(){timestart()};
function timestart() {
    pantplay.style="display: ";
    pantprincipal.style="display: none";
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){pantplay.style="display: none";
        puntuator.style="display: ";
        puntuation.innerHTML=x;
        closepunt.onclick=function() {closepuntuation()};}, 2*1000);
}
catbutton.onclick=function(){timecancel()}
cubebutton.onclick=function(){timecancel()}
function timecancel() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
var x=0;
var arr= ["cat1.jpg", "cat2.jpg", "cat3.jpg", "cat4.jpg", "cat5.jpg", "cat6.jpg", "cat7.jpg", "cat8.jpg", "cat9.jpg","cube1.jpg", "cube2.jpg", "cube3.jpg", "cube4.jpg", "cube5.jpg", "cube6.jpg", "cube7.jpg", "cube8.jpg"];
let randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
console.log(randomElement);
image.src=(randomElement);
catbutton.onclick=function(){catfunction()};
function catfunction(){
    if (randomElement=="cat1.jpg" || randomElement=="cat2.jpg" || randomElement=="cat3.jpg" || randomElement=="cat4.jpg" || randomElement=="cat5.jpg" || randomElement=="cat6.jpg" || randomElement=="cat7.jpg" || randomElement=="cat8.jpg" || randomElement=="cat9.jpg"){
        x++;
        randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement);
        console.log(randomElement);
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else{
        pantplay.style="display: none";
        puntuator.style="display: ";
        puntuation.innerHTML=x;
        closepunt.onclick=function(){closepuntuation()};
    }
}
cubebutton.onclick=function(){cubefunction()};
function cubefunction(){
    if (randomElement=="cube1.jpg" || randomElement=="cube2.jpg" || randomElement=="cube3.jpg" || randomElement=="cube4.jpg" || randomElement=="cube5.jpg" || randomElement=="cube6.jpg" || randomElement=="cube7.jpg" || randomElement=="cube8.jpg"){
        x++;
        randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement);
        console.log(randomElement);
        image.src=(randomElement);
    }
    else{
        pantplay.style="display: none";
        puntuator.style="display: ";
        puntuation.innerHTML=x;
        closepunt.onclick=function() {closepuntuation()};
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you first set onclick event to

```
catbutton.onclick=function(){timecancel()}
cubebutton.onclick=function(){timecancel()}
```

but then you override it later by setting the onclick event anew.

Use `addEventListener` instead like

```
catbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){timecancel()});
cubebutton.addEventListener('click', function(){timecancel()});

// and later
catbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){catfunction()});
cubebutton.addEventListener('click', function(){cubefunction()});
```

or combine both functions into just one event listener:

```
catbutton.onclick=function(){timecancel(); catfunction();}
cubebutton.onclick=function(){timecancel(); cubefunction(); }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If I want to do the time starts another time, should I add ```timeoutID = setTimeout(function(){pantplay.style="display: none";
        puntuator.style="display: ";
        puntuation.innerHTML=x;
        closepunt.onclick=function() {closepuntuation()};}, 2*1000);
```
in ```canceltime``` to stop time and start counting time from 0?

Comment: The code in comments is hard to read, but sure, you can set the timeout anew in `timecancel` after you clear the previous timeout.